# How to populate a dropdown in html5 from a sqlite database?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have the database up and running and I have a dropdown I want to fill with entries from the database.

I haven't found a way to, so any nudge in the right direction would be great.
I'm not a web developer at all, but have been given a web project. :s

I'm using html5 and javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestTest</title>
    <script>var newdb = openDatabase('mydb3', '1.02', 'Test DB1', 100 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
newdb.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "Item 1")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "Item 2")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (4, "Item 3")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (5, "Item 4")');
msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
});

newdb.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;
msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
  msg = results.rows.item(i);
  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
  document.getElementById("Select1").options.add(msg);
 }
}, null);
});

<div id="list" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px;width:100px;">
   <select name="drop1" form="List" id="Select1" size="13" onchange="playAlert(this)">
       <option value="1111111">Field Number item 1</option>
   </select>

</div>
```

Comment: If this javascript is executed on a client browser, the security is not going to allow you to access the system in any way.

Comment: Typically you set up SQL lite as a data source and use PHP or C# or some other server-side language to generate the HTML.